# hide field in OpenERP module using javascript

Tags: javascript, openerp-7

I just want to hide field which I added to model *sales.order.line* and added it to *sale.order.form*. I tried below code:

```
openerp.sales_extra  = function(instance){
// module code goes here
console.log('My module has been initialized');
var MODELS_TO_HIDE = ['sale.order.line'];
openerp.web.FormView.include({
    start: function() {
    // on_loaded: function(data) {
        var self = this;
        var ret = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        var res_model = this.dataset.model;
        if ($.inArray(res_model, MODELS_TO_HIDE) != -1) {
            //this.$element.find('add_to_inv').remove();
            this.$element.find('add_to_inv').hide();//this the field which i want to hide
        };
        return ret;
    },
});
```

};

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'include' of undefined
```

Another Question if this field is boolean in my OpenERP module how to know if it checked or not in js?

Answer (score 0):

As of OpenERP 7.0, for a starter, you have to

```
instance.web.FormView = instance.web.FormView.extend({
```

instead of

```
openerp.web.FormView.include({
```

And this just as an appetizer.

Comment: I don't know, but I guess. However the point I want to remark is that using either 7 or 8 anyway, the necessary code is so different from that 6.1 snippet, that I think you should get the browser development console and handcraft it all over by yourself.